# Android - Cannot get TextView to wrap text

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap

I have a layout with some controls. I want a particular TextView to wrap text.
I have already search for google on how to to wrap text, but none worked for me.

**Description**
Find the `Address` control in the code bellow, which is the `TextView` with the long text.
Notice the `Address` control is placed in a  `LinearLayout`. I was hoping the `Address` control wouldn't go outside the LinearLayout's layout.
When the TextView's text is long, the text goes behind the `RightIcon` control and continues forever to the right.

**Question**
How to cause the text to wrap and use a line bellow inside the `LinearLayout` an not go behind the `RightIcon` control?

**Code** (stripped from all non-necessary code)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- LeftIcon -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/leftIcon"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="X"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/leftIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" >

        <!-- Address -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize=20sp"
            tools:text="An address which is very long and must wrap to a line bellow" />

        <!-- Person 1 -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/person1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="Person 1" />

        <!-- Person 2 -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/person2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="Person 2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- RightIcon -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rightIcon"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:text="Y"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Limit the views width. You have `wrap_content`, it gives it's width based on the text and it can be more than of its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LinearLayout, you could add a connect to right icon:

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rightIcon"
```

and change width of linear layout to "0dp".